# TicTacToe program going into an infinite loop (C++)

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

I've made a simple Tic Tac Toe game for 2 players, but whenever I launch it it goes into some sort of infinite loop after the first choice and can't be played.

I ended up using system("pause") and it ended up working but I don't want it to work like that, if anyone can explain to me the reasons of the bug.

Here's my code: (Some function and variable names are in french sorry for that, just ask if you don't get something but it is nothing complicated)

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
char joueur = 'X';
char jeu [3][3]={{'1','2','3'},{'4','5','6'},{'7','8','9'}};

void Terrain()
{
    system("cls");
    cout<<"TicTacToe V1.0 by Zeoun\n";
    cout<<"Joueur 1: X | Joueur 2: O\n";
    cout<<"       -----------\n";
    cout<<"      | "<<jeu[0][0]<<" | "<<jeu[0][1]<<" | "<<jeu[0][2]<<" |\n";
    cout<<"       -----------\n";
    cout<<"      | "<<jeu[1][0]<<" | "<<jeu[1][1]<<" | "<<jeu[1][2]<<" |\n";
    cout<<"       -----------\n";
    cout<<"      | "<<jeu[2][0]<<" | "<<jeu[2][1]<<" | "<<jeu[2][2]<<" |\n";
    cout<<"       -----------\n";
}
void Tour()
{
    if (joueur=='X')
    {
        joueur = 'O';
    }
    else if (joueur=='O')
    {
        joueur = 'X';
    }
}
void Choix()
{
    int a;
    while(a<1||a>9)
    {
        cout << "Choisis une case pour jouer: ";
        cin >> a;
        if (a==1 && jeu[0][0]!= 'X' && jeu[0][0]!= 'O')
            jeu[0][0]=joueur;
        else if (a==2 && jeu[0][1]!= 'X' && jeu[0][1]!= 'O')
            jeu[0][1]=joueur;
        else if (a==3 && jeu[0][2]!= 'X' && jeu[0][2]!= 'O')
            jeu[0][2]=joueur;
        else if (a==4 && jeu[1][0]!= 'X' && jeu[1][0]!= 'O')
            jeu[1][0]=joueur;
        else if (a==5 && jeu[1][1]!= 'X' && jeu[1][1]!= 'O')
            jeu[1][1]=joueur;
        else if (a==6 && jeu[1][2]!= 'X' && jeu[1][2]!= 'O')
            jeu[1][2]=joueur;
        else if (a==7 && jeu[2][0]!= 'X' && jeu[2][0]!= 'O')
            jeu[2][0]=joueur;
        else if (a==8 && jeu[2][1]!= 'X' && jeu[2][1]!= 'O')
            jeu[2][1]=joueur;
        else if (a==9 && jeu[2][2]!= 'X' && jeu[2][2]!= 'O')
            jeu[2][2]=joueur;
        else 
        {
            cout<<"Invalide.\n";
            Tour();
        }
    }
}
int Win()
{
    //victoirejoueur1
    if (jeu[0][0]==jeu[0][1]&&jeu[0][1]==jeu[0][2]&&jeu[0][0]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[1][0]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][0]==jeu[1][2]&&jeu[1][0]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[2][0]==jeu[2][1]&&jeu[2][1]==jeu[2][2]&&jeu[2][0]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][0]==jeu[1][0]&&jeu[1][0]==jeu[2][0]&&jeu[0][0]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][1]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][1]==jeu[2][1]&&jeu[0][1]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][2]==jeu[1][2]&&jeu[1][2]==jeu[2][2]&&jeu[0][2]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][0]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][1]==jeu[2][2]&&jeu[0][0]=='X')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][2]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][1]==jeu[2][0]&&jeu[0][2]=='X')
        return 1;
    //victoirejoueur2
    else if (jeu[0][0]==jeu[0][1]&&jeu[0][1]==jeu[0][2]&&jeu[0][0]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[1][0]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][0]==jeu[1][2]&&jeu[1][0]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[2][0]==jeu[2][1]&&jeu[2][1]==jeu[2][2]&&jeu[2][0]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][0]==jeu[1][0]&&jeu[1][0]==jeu[2][0]&&jeu[0][0]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][1]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][1]==jeu[2][1]&&jeu[0][1]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][2]==jeu[1][2]&&jeu[1][2]==jeu[2][2]&&jeu[0][2]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][0]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][1]==jeu[2][2]&&jeu[0][0]=='O')
        return 1;
    else if (jeu[0][2]==jeu[1][1]&&jeu[1][1]==jeu[2][0]&&jeu[0][2]=='O')
        return 1;
    //pasdevictoire
    else
        return 0;
}
bool egalite()
{
    if(jeu[0][0]=='X'||jeu[0][0]=='O')
    {
        if(jeu[0][1]=='X'||jeu[0][1]=='O')
        {
            if(jeu[0][2]=='X'||jeu[0][2]=='O')
            {
                if(jeu[1][0]=='X'||jeu[1][0]=='O')
                {
                    if(jeu[1][1]=='X'||jeu[1][1]=='O')
                    {
                        if(jeu[1][2]=='X'||jeu[1][2]=='O')
                        {
                            if(jeu[2][0]=='X'||jeu[2][0]=='O')
                            {
                                if(jeu[2][1]=='X'||jeu[2][1]=='O')
                                {
                                    if(jeu[2][2]=='X'||jeu[2][2]=='O')
                                    {
                                        if(Win()==0)
                                        {
                                            return true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    else
        return false;
return false;
}

int main()
{
    Terrain();
    Win();
    while(Win()==0&&egalite()==false)
    {
        Win();
        Choix();
        Terrain();
        Tour();
        egalite();
       system("pause");
    }
    if(egalite()==true)
        cout<<"Egalite !\n";
    if(Win()==1)
        cout<<"Le joueur 1 a gagne !\n";
    if(Win()==2)
        cout<<"Le joueur 2 a gagne !\n";
system("pause");
}
```

(Btw, égalité means tie, joueur means player, tour means turn)

Comment: This is not flippant advice: learn to use your debugger, then step through your code and inspect variables in real time. Compare your observations to your expectations. Right now you're asking us to do the job of a program that's freely available.

Comment: Maybe, this is a good opportunity to learn how to use the debugger. Just a hint: When debugging, please, focus on `void Choix()`. You have the `while (a<1||a>9)` but what value has `int a;` at the time when the condition is tested the first time? (What if it's "accidentally" inside of [1, 9]?)

Comment: Did you happen to enter something that's not an integer? It works [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ca5c489a46b90475) (I added the missing initialization of `a`.)

Comment: Are yo aware there is logical operator `&&` so you do not have use this ugly  `if` chain?

Comment: You call `Win()` many times throwing away the value it returns. I don't see the point in that.